# How to make a combined histogram of two grouped columns?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE57r.png)
I have these data as attached and I'm trying to make overlap the Home and Away Histogram for **each** team individually? I'm new to python btw.

So far I made which looks exactly what I want but I want to combine them again by each team:

```
df_EPL['Away_score'].hist(by=df_EPL['AwayTeam'],figsize = (8,8),color = '#96ddff');
```

and

```
df_EPL['Home_score'].hist(by=df_EPL['HomeTeam'],figsize = (8,8),color = '#82c065');
```

Comment: Don't paste images of code or data. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Please indicate the expected output (what the "combined histogram" should look like).

Comment: Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fake Dataframe creation

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


np.random.seed(42)
teams = ['Arsenal', 'Chelsea', 'Liverpool', 'Manchester City', 'Manchester Utd']

df = pd.DataFrame({'HomeTeam': np.repeat(teams, len(teams) - 1)})
df['AwayTeam'] = [away_team for home_team in teams for away_team in teams if away_team != home_team]
df['Home_score'] = np.random.randint(0, 5, len(df))
df['Away_score'] = np.random.randint(0, 5, len(df))
```

```
           HomeTeam         AwayTeam  Home_score  Away_score
0           Arsenal          Chelsea           3           1
1           Arsenal        Liverpool           4           4
2           Arsenal  Manchester City           2           3
3           Arsenal   Manchester Utd           4           0
4           Chelsea          Arsenal           4           0
5           Chelsea        Liverpool           1           2
6           Chelsea  Manchester City           2           2
7           Chelsea   Manchester Utd           2           1
8         Liverpool          Arsenal           2           3
9         Liverpool          Chelsea           4           3
10        Liverpool  Manchester City           3           2
11        Liverpool   Manchester Utd           2           3
12  Manchester City          Arsenal           4           3
13  Manchester City          Chelsea           1           0
14  Manchester City        Liverpool           3           2
15  Manchester City   Manchester Utd           1           4
16   Manchester Utd          Arsenal           3           2
17   Manchester Utd          Chelsea           4           4
18   Manchester Utd        Liverpool           0           0
19   Manchester Utd  Manchester City           3           1
```

### Dataframe re-shape

You need to re-shape your dataframe in a different format in order to make the plot you want. For this purpose, you can use [**`pandas.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = pd.melt(frame = df,
             id_vars = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam'],
             var_name = 'H/A',
             value_name = 'Score')

df = df.drop('AwayTeam', axis = 1).rename(columns = {'HomeTeam': 'Team'}).replace({'Home_score': 'Home', 'Away_score': 'Away'})
```

```
               Team   H/A  Score
0           Arsenal  Home      3
1           Arsenal  Home      4
2           Arsenal  Home      2
3           Arsenal  Home      4
4           Chelsea  Home      4
5           Chelsea  Home      1
6           Chelsea  Home      2
7           Chelsea  Home      2
8         Liverpool  Home      2
9         Liverpool  Home      4
10        Liverpool  Home      3
11        Liverpool  Home      2
12  Manchester City  Home      4
13  Manchester City  Home      1
14  Manchester City  Home      3
15  Manchester City  Home      1
16   Manchester Utd  Home      3
17   Manchester Utd  Home      4
18   Manchester Utd  Home      0
19   Manchester Utd  Home      3
20          Arsenal  Away      1
21          Arsenal  Away      4
22          Arsenal  Away      3
23          Arsenal  Away      0
24          Chelsea  Away      0
25          Chelsea  Away      2
26          Chelsea  Away      2
27          Chelsea  Away      1
28        Liverpool  Away      3
29        Liverpool  Away      3
30        Liverpool  Away      2
31        Liverpool  Away      3
32  Manchester City  Away      3
33  Manchester City  Away      0
34  Manchester City  Away      2
35  Manchester City  Away      4
36   Manchester Utd  Away      2
37   Manchester Utd  Away      4
38   Manchester Utd  Away      0
39   Manchester Utd  Away      1
```

### Plot

Now dataframe is ready to be plotted. You can use [**`seaborn.FacetGrid`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) to create the grid of subplots, one for each team. Each subplot will have two [**`seaborn.histplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html): one for `Home_score` and one for `Away_score`:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col = 'Team', hue = 'H/A')
g.map(sns.histplot, 'Score', bins = np.arange(df['Score'].min() - 0.5, df['Score'].max() + 1.5, 1))
g.add_legend()
g.set(xticks = np.arange(df['Score'].min(), df['Score'].max() + 1, 1))

plt.show()
```

[image]